# Remove grunt from IntelliSense autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code

Background:
Every time I type in log, this Grunt intellisense I never asked for pops up as the first option, which causes me to accidentally add some grunt code on a project with no grunt instance. How do I get rid of this or at least bump it down in priority? I don't have any grunt extensions installed on VS Code.

[image]

Steps:

1. Open a JS file in vs code
2. Type log
3. hit enter/tab

**Expected behavior:**
get console.log() ready to roll

**Actual behavior:**
get a bunch of grunt code that doesn't belong in a vanilla JS file

Comment: is grunt one of the direct dependencies of your project listed in your package.json? or is it a transitive dependency? are you using npm? out of curiosity, if you are, any difference if you nuke node_modules and install using pnpm instead?

Comment: grunt is not a dependency on this project and there is no npm for this project.

Comment: do you have automatic type acquisition enabled?

Comment: it appears so, I disabled and got the same behavior

Comment: try manually deleting that type package now and see if it gets automatically installed again. should be able to find where it was installed to by ctrl+click on the import